# Create and upload build ipa file in app store after creating game application in libgdx

Tags: ios, iphone, gradle, libgdx, ipa

I have created a gaming application in libgdx and I intend to upload the binary file (.ipa) in apple app store. But I am clueless about how to generate the ipa file and upload it in the apple app store.

Please throw some light on the procedure to be followed.

Comment: This question is just to general.

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution myself. By using gradle we can generate an ipa and then upload the binary using application loader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now Libgdx default support Gradle Build ,You can simply generate using gradl build cammand